# vue router.replace acts differently based on how input object is assembled

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vue-router

I encountered some weird behaviour with Vue Router where the router acts differently based on how it's input object is assembled. The code sample below is an except from a component's 'methods' property. See the comments in my code sample for more info.

```
switchLocale(newLocale) {
                // this solution works
                const route = {
                    name: this.$route.name,
                    query: {locale: newLocale},
                    params: this.$route.params,
                };
                console.log(JSON.stringify(route));
                // {"name":"v.support.help","query":{"locale":"en"},"params":{}}
                this.$router.replace(route);

                // this solution does not change the route. I would expect it to work exactly like the solution above
                /*
                const {name, query, params} = this.$route;
                let route = {name, query, params};
                route.query.locale = newLocale;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(route));
                // {"name":"v.support.help","query":{"locale":"en"},"params":{}}
                this.$router.replace(route);
                */
            }
```

What could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second code, you're mutating the `this.$route.query` object directly and passing it to `this.$router.replace`. I'm guessing vue-router will not be able to detect if the query has changed because you mutated vue-router's internal state.

Do not mutate the `this.$route` object (or any of Vue's internal state for that matter) otherwise things may not work properly.

If you want to preserve the existing query parameters while introducing or changing another one, then you can do this:

```
this.$router.replace({
  query: Object.assign({}, this.$route.query, { locale: newLocale }),
  // No need to specify route name and params, they will be preserved
});
```